# How can I get my android app to execute code when a notification is received when it's in background?

Tags: java, android, firebase, service, notifications

I'm trying to program a remote alarm clock application for Android, because my friend sometimes misses her train or is too early (I don't want to wake up, but just want her to set my alarm clock time).

I figured out how to set the alarm clock using Java in just a couple of minutes, but that **function must be executed remotely. How to do that?**

At the moment I'm using `Googles Firebase Cloud Messaging service` to send notifications including the time for the alarm clock as parameters.
However, when I receive them and *the app isn't open*, *it doesn't execute any code*, but waits until the user taps on the notification. But what I want the app to do is `set the alarm clock automatically when a notification is received`.

I know this does probably violate a bunch of security guidelines, but this isn't an app for the **PlayStore**, but just for myself.

My idea is to built some kind of service that's active all the time in the *background waiting for notifications*. **Do you think something like that is possible?**

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass notification payload to the service class and there you can set alarm manager in the background.

Comment: I have no Service at the moment. I only have a Main Activity and I have no influence on the notification payload.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is silent notification. which will not even appear just set an alarm once it reaches to the device. So to handle that you get the notification from broadcast receiver and send it to Service class.  there you can handle what you want to do. Without opening app.

Comment: Okay. But how can I get the notification recognised by the broadcast receiver?

Comment: While implementing FCM you must have registered Broadcast receiver to listen for notifications. In onReceive of that send the payload to Service.

Comment: So far I have extended the FirebaseMessagingService class provided by the Firebase API and have overwritten onMessageReceived.

But that void is only executed, when the notification is displayed when the app is active.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot get notification information when app killed or at background, but if notification arrived, the onCreate of FirebaseMessagingService will be fired, so we could try to get notification information from your backend server in onCreate.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "in onCreate, try to get informations from backend server, ex..send http request here");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems helpful, I'll try it.

Comment: I don't want to launch the activity, but need access to the notification (even if the device is locked)

Comment: I think there is no way to access the notification when you app at background,but you can get the information from your backend server. In my case, I access the back-end server in onCreate, ex, send http request to get the notification count to show badge count on launch icon.